# Querying related model with parent model id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models:

```
class UserPost(models.Model, Activity):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userpost', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
```

The second model would be:

```
class UserPostComment(models.Model, Activity):
post = models.ForeignKey(UserPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userpostcomment')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userpost_comment_user')
comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

TO get the UserPostComment model using the foreignkey *post*. I did:

```
UserPostComment.objects.get(post_id=post_id)
```

This query only works when I have one UserPostComment entry. When there are more than one comment, It fails.

I would get:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /comment/268/
get() returned more than one UserPostComment -- it returned 2!
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: So, you can use .filter like this UserPostComment.objects.filter(post_id=post_id), or you have some other query about whats happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get return only one value use filter instead of get

```
UserPostComment.objects.filter(post_id=post_id)
```